# Why does Windows 10 sometimes show that annoying, impossible-to-remove red "update pending" icon in the Notification area?

Tags: windows-10, security, updates, notification-area

I get it. It want me to reboot/shut down so it can apply the pending update. I'm going to bed in a couple of hours and then it will get its chance. Why can't I make it go away until then? I keep looking at that damn icon every few seconds. It's incredibly distracting. It cannot be removed in any way that I've found, and is obviously designed to be impossible to get rid of.

The issue is that I can't reboot *right now* and lose all my work/"state" and have to wait forever as everything I have to run at startup to slowly make its way back to a usable state. It's a chore alone to close all the stuff I'm doing. It's simply not practical to reboot whenever Windows thinks feels like it.

I've already gone through all the settings in the entire OS to make it respect me as much as possible, but it still shows that icon.

You'd think that their "AI" would know that I always shut down my machine every day for the night, and not feel the need to force-display that icon until I give in. If it's some kind of critical "0-day hack" that's being fixed, I would understand it, but if such is the case, and I'm vulnerable every minute I remain online, I would actually want it to *force* me to restart immediately -- not just "subtly" display that nag icon in the Notification area.

This doesn't happen all the time. Usually, I see no visual or other indication whatsoever about there being a pending update until I actually shut down the machine. It will say: "Updating: 36%" etc. for a few seconds and that's it. Just as it should be.

How come it sometimes makes this annoying icon with the big red dot persistently stick to the bottom-right part of my screen? What does that mean? Is it for extra serious patches?

Comment: I do this differently than you. If you do updates on shutdown, it will (most of the time) do more updates the next startup to complete the job. I would rather have updates completed.  I set Active and Off Hours (Update settings) and leave the machine on overnight to complete the task. If I have a spare moment (it seems most people in here do not have any spare moments), I close apps and files and let the machine update. This overall process works well and any notification I get can be dismissed with "Later".

Comment: Can you not right click the notification icon and clear it? I don't have any pending updates on any machine to check, but I am almost certain that you can right click that icon and clear the notification for a couple hours or next reboot.